# How can i remove a particular text from a file in java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, filereader

I have tried to implement a simple program to delete a particular text from a file, some how it is not able to delete it. I am reading entire file content into a temp file , delete the user input string from it and update the content to the original file.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
public class TextEraser{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
            
            
            System.out.print("Enter a string to remove  : ");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in);
            String inputString = scanner. nextLine();
            
            // Locate the  file
            File file = new File("/Users/lobsang/documents/input.txt");
            
            //create temporary file 
            
            File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", file.getParentFile());

            String charset = "UTF-8";
            
            

            try {
                
                // Create a buffered reader
                // to read each line from a file.
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));

                String s = in.readLine();

                // Read each line from the file and echo it to the screen.
                while (s !=null) {
                    
                          s=s.replace(inputString,"");
                          s = in.readLine();

                }
                

                writer.println(s);
                
                // Close the buffered reader
                in.close();
                writer.close();
                
                file.delete();
                temp.renameTo(file);
                


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // If this file does not exist
                System.err.println("File not found: " + file);

            
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are replacing the input string with empty string, which is ok, and store it to `s`.  Afterwards you read the next line and override `s` again.  You didn't do anything with the replaced line.  You will want to write the replaced string to the output file, so add a line after `s=s.replace(inputString,"");` to do so.

Comment: so i believe s=s.replace(inputstring,""). -- does replace the user input string with empty string if its in that line ...  and then  in the end i am wrting that line to temp file with writer.println(s)..       am i missing some thing ...   can you please give me little more detials ..quite lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replace with input string, write string immediate in file.

```
while (s != null) {
    s = s.replace(inputString, "");
    writer.write(s);
    // writer.newLine();
    s = in.readLine();
}
```

For new line , use BufferedWriter in place of PrintWriter, it contains method newLine()

```
writer.newLine();
```

Remove this

```
writer.println(s);
```